# Sending Image in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, image, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to send an image in as3, since some images are to big, I tried to split the image apart and then send them, after that reassemble them. This is the code:

The Sender Code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class test extends Sprite
    {
        private var socket:DatagramSocket;
        private var r:FileReference;
        private var loader:Loader;
        public function test()
        {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.bind(12395, "127.0.0.1");
            r = new FileReference();
            r.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, loadFile);
            r.browse();
        }

        protected function loadFile(event:Event):void
        {
            r.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendFile);
            r.load();
        }

        protected function sendFile(event:Event):void
        {
            var b:ByteArray;
            trace(r.data.bytesAvailable);
            for(var i:uint = 0; i < r.data.bytesAvailable;)
            {
                b = new ByteArray();
                if(r.data.bytesAvailable >= 1024)
                {
                    r.data.readBytes(b, 0, 1024);
                    socket.send(b, 0, 0, "127.0.0.1", 12345);
                    trace(b.bytesAvailable);
                    trace(r.data.bytesAvailable);
                }
                else
                {
                    r.data.readBytes(b, i, r.data.bytesAvailable);
                    socket.send(b, 0, 0, "127.0.0.1", 12345);
                    b = new ByteArray();
                    socket.send(b, 0, 0, "127.0.0.1", 12345);
                    trace(b.bytesAvailable);
                    trace(r.data.bytesAvailable);
                    break;
                }           

            }

            trace("----------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

The Receiver Code:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.DatagramSocketDataEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.DatagramSocket;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
var socket:DatagramSocket;
var loader:Loader;
var b:ByteArray;
var i:uint = 0;
b = new ByteArray();
socket = new DatagramSocket();
socket.bind(12345, "127.0.0.1");
socket.addEventListener(DatagramSocketDataEvent.DATA, handleData);
socket.receive();
function handleData(event:DatagramSocketDataEvent):void
{

    if(event.data.bytesAvailable != 0)
    {
        trace("writing bytes...");
        event.data.readBytes(b, i);
        trace(b.bytesAvailable);
        //b.length = b.length + 1;
        i = i + 1024;
    }
    else
    {
        loadImg();
    }
}

function loadImg():void
{
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addToStage);
    loader.loadBytes(b);
}
function addToStage(event:Event):void
{
    addChild(loader);
}
```

But the image does't load, even though the sent and the received bytes are exactly equal.

Comment: In your sendFile, how does the i get incremented? I get the impression you never get out of that loop?

Comment: No need for increment, because the loop will break when the byte array is out of bytes. I also tested it and it did get out of the loop.

Comment: If i is then a constant, always equal to 0, what does r.data.readBytes(b, i, r.data.bytesAvailable) do?

Answer (score 0):

I just simply modify on sender code as below:

---

```
else
{
 r.data.readBytes(b, i, r.data.bytesAvailable);
 socket.send(b, 0, 0, "127.0.0.1", 12345);
 b = new ByteArray();
 b.writeByte(0)       // ADD THIS NEW LINE
 socket.send(b, 0, 0, "127.0.0.1", 12345);
 trace(b.bytesAvailable);
 trace(r.data.bytesAvailable);
 break;
}
```

---

And it will fire the loadImg function.